# How to load balance connecting to SignalR server

Tags: signalr, load-balancing

I have multiple SignalR servers and want to load balance them. I use Redis backplane for communication between servers.

But I don't know how can I do it. I wanted to do something like it:

1. End-user sends request to load balancer that faces Internet.
2. The load balancer returns access token (short lifetime) and URI indicating SignalR server to which the end-user should connect.
3. The SignalR server exposes endpoint used to connect via WebSocket. The endpoint requires authorization by access token provided by load balancer (so I can be sure that every connection request is load balanced)

But how can I achieve this with SignalR? I think I need to disable default endpoint for connecting with WebSockets (so I can use access token).

*Maybe I misunderstood how load balancing works? I assumed that connections to SignalR are not through load balancer, because I would need to load balance the load balancer? (One load balancer cannot handle connections to all SignalR servers)*